# How to call javascript function erverytime when i click to open Bootstarp Modal using Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I want to call javascript function when i click an link and open a Bootstarp Modal.

When first time Bootstarp Modal load then function called but when i closed Bootstrap Modal and again click on same link and open same Bootstrap Modal then Function is not called.

I want to call function everytime when i open Bootstrap Modal.

Bootstrap Call Function :

```
$(document).on("click", "#update_project_image_modal", function() {
    var cid = $(this).data('id');
     console.log(cid);
     $.ajax({
         url: '<?=$this->config->base_url()?>admin_panel/update_project_images_popup',
         type: 'post',
         data: 'project_id=' + cid
     }).done(function(data) {
         jQuery('#categoryModal .modal-content').html(data);
         $('#categoryModal').modal({
            "backdrop" : "static"
        });
     });
 });
```

Function Call In Bootstrap Modal Load :

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log('ready');
listFilesOnServer();
});
```

HTML Table (Where i click link to open Bootstarp Modal) :

```
<table id="table3" class="display table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> Location</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>jkhjk</td>
            <td>kjhjk</td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="update_project_image_modal" data-id="225"> Images</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you add your html

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options

Comment: $('#modalID').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { //your code });

Comment: use alert("hello");  on onclick() of button to debug

Comment: I added HTML Code also

Comment: @Kunal, onclick is working thats why Modal is open everytime but on Modal load function is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has an event which is triggered when the modal is called:

[show.bs.modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

> This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
>   If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the
>   relatedTarget property of the event.

In your case you would use it like so:

```
$('#categoryModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(evt){
    listFilesOnServer();
});
```